# Creating a fixed sidebar without taking it out of flow

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am trying to create a website which has a sidebar on the right which is fixed to the screen and takes up 100% of the page. I want my container's width set as 100%, filling the remaining space after taking account for whatever the width of my sidebar is. I need the sidebar to remain stationary as the user scrolls down the page. I would like the height of my sidebar to be a percentage based value. How would I go about doing this?

If I were to use "Position: fixed", it would take the sidebar out of flow causing the container to span the whole width of the page, ignoring the width of the sidebar. This causes issues when I try and apply "text-align: center".

Here is a visual representation of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: what i would like]

Comment: and are you expecting us to do it for you?

Answer (score 2):

Just put `.body{ margin-right: 80px`} (i.e. the size of your sidebar) and then position fixed on your sidebar.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/vv84cd08/1/